# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert some data to my table in MSSQL using flask+sqlalchemy. I'm using Python 3.4.
My code:

```
@main.route('/create-user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_user():
    form = NewUser()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        login = form.name.data
        passwrd = form.password.data
        print (login) #getting login is ok
        print (passwrd) #same
        engine.execute(
            text("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ((CONVERT(binary, :login)), (CONVERT(binary, :passwrd)))"), login, passwrd)

        session.commit()
        flash('Succesfull')
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
    return render_template('new_user.html', form=form)
```

But im getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\flask_prj\project\app\main\views.py", line 35, in create_user
    text("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ((CONVERT(binary, :login)), (CONVERT(binary, :passwrd)))"), login, passwrd)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1751, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 729, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 802, in _execute_clauseelement
    keys = distilled_params[0].keys()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

How i can handle this problem?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use named placeholders in your sql, you'll have to provide the parameters as keyword arguments.

So, e.g.:

```
engine.execute(text("... ((CONVERT(binary, :login)), (CONVERT(binary, :passwrd)))"),
               login=login, passwrd=passwrd)
```

or, use positional placeholders:

```
engine.execute(text("... ((CONVERT(binary, %s)), (CONVERT(binary, %s)))"),
               login, passwrd)
```

Depending on what mssql connector you're actually using, you might have to replace `%s` with `?` in the latter case.

Comment: From SQLA 2.0, the parameters must be passed as a dictionary (or list of dictionaries for `executemany`  style inserts etc).