# Variable Placeholders: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have read a similar issue ([AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628878/attributeerror-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-keys)) and Psycopg's official documentation on placeholders for variables, but I am still getting stuck on what seems to be a most simple query. Sorry for asking this , but what's wrong with the various iterations I have tried?

```
    cur.execute('''
    UPDATE scrape_log 
    SET date_added=%s, result_count=%s 
    WHERE start_date=%s AND end_date=%s
    ''', date_scraped, result_count, start_date, end_date)
```

It returned `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'`.

I also tried the following, but it returned the same error.

```
    cur.execute('''
    UPDATE scrape_log 
    SET VALUES (%s, %s)
    WHERE start_date=(%s) AND end_date=(%s)
    ''', (date_scraped, result_count), (start_date,), (end_date,))
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   cur.execute('''
    UPDATE scrape_log 
    SET date_added=%s, result_count=%s 
    WHERE start_date=%s AND end_date=%s
    ''', (date_scraped, result_count, start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: Oh yes, this is one of the many I've tried. It returns the same error, for some reason.

Comment: Ah, I found an issue with one of the variables; fixed it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should be enclosed in a tuple, so try this:

```
cur.execute('''
    UPDATE scrape_log 
    SET date_added=%s, result_count=%s 
    WHERE start_date=%s AND end_date=%s
    ''', (date_scraped, result_count, start_date, end_date))
```

Comment: I thought it was the issue, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I found an issue with one of the variables; fixed it and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 query = """ UPDATE books
                SET title = %s
                WHERE id = %s """

    data = (title, book_id)

 cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using your query is something lije this

```
query = "UPDATE scrape_log SET date_added=%s, result_count=%s 
    WHERE start_date=%s AND end_date=%s"

  cur.execute(query, (date_scraped, result_count, start_date, end_date,))
```